# Tiny MCE editor display doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, tinymce

When I change the font size or font style in tiny mce editor and hit save and view my page, it displays correct font size and style on the form .
When I open editor again  the editor doesn't display correct font size or style.
(only IE9 issue).IE9 doesn't display styles and size of fone as selected and saved before. firefox displays it right.

HTML

```
            <textarea class="news-copy"
                        data-bind="
                            tinymce: Copy,
                            tinymceOptions: { 
                                plugins: 'paste,searchreplace',
                                content_css: 'Styles/ControlCSS/MainPage.css',
                                toolbar2: 'fontselect,fontsizeselect',
                                menubar: false,
                                statusbar: false,
                                browser_spellcheck: true,
                                valid_elements: '',
                                body_class: 'mainpage-container-text'
                            },                              
                            autoActivate: false">
            </textarea>
```

IE9

[image: IE9]

Firefox
[image: Firefox image]
It seems like some cleanup utility is removing span tag with font size in IE.

```
    <html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta content="IE=7" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/myapplication/Scripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/o2k7/content.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/myapplication/Styles/ControlCSS/MainPage.css">
</head>
<body dir="ltr" id="tinymce" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('mce_0').onLoad.dispatch();" class="mceContentBody mainpage-container-text" contentEditable="true">
<p>Hello Test &nbsp; &nbsp; Test1
</p>
</body>
```

---

Firefox- firebug

```
<html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta content="IE=7" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link href="http://localhost/myapplication/Scripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/o2k7/content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://localhost/myapplication/Styles/ControlCSS/MainPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('mce_0').onLoad.dispatch();" class="mceContentBody mainpage-container-text" id="tinymce" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr">
<p>Hello 
<span data-mce-style="font-size: 14pt;" style="font-size: 14pt;">Test &nbsp; &nbsp;</span> 
<span data-mce-style="font-size: 18pt;" style="font-size: 18pt;">Test1</span>
</p>
</body>
```

Tiny MCE Configuration

```
 tinymceOptions: {
                // Default Theme options:
                // "setup" can not be overridden instead use onBeforeTinyMCESetup and onAfterTinyMCESetup
                mode: 'none',
                theme: 'advanced',
                plugins: 'paste,searchreplace,legacyoutput',
                skin: 'o2k7',
                skin_variant: 'silver',
                content_css: '../../Styles/RadEditor_CourierNew.css',
                paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
                valid_elements: '@[align],b/strong,i/em,strike/s,u,br,p,div',
                theme_advanced_buttons1: 
                    'bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,' +
                    '|,cut,copy,paste,selectall,' +
                    '|,undo,redo,' + 
                    '|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,' +
                    '|,search,replace,help,spellcheck',
                theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
                theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
                theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
                theme_advanced_toolbar_align: 'left'
            },
            radSpellCheckID: null,
            onBeforeTinyMCESetup: null,
            onAfterTinyMCESetup: null,
            onTinyMCEBlur: null,
            delayEditorDisplay: true,
            htmlEncode: true,
            displayFontFamily: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
            displayFontSize: '11px'
        };
```

Comment: can you show me the respective html of your editor content (use the code plugin!) ?

Comment: i have not asked for the tinymce version but your editor content htmal code!

Comment: I have added html code above images. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks

Comment: this is not the editor content!

Comment: I just added html from IE & firefox. it seems like in IE some cleanup utility of tiny mce is removing span tag with font size & style.

Comment: that's why i am asking for the editor content

Comment: Sorry I am new to tiny mce , using it very 1st time and don't know exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: tinymce is not equal the textarea. tinymce creates oninit a contenteditable iframe where the content can be edited. the editor content gets written back to the textarea later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

 ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
                           $element.tinymce().setContent(value, { format: 'raw' });
                        });
```